# How to join not relational model in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i have a problem about join not relational model in django rest framework. for example, i have two model :

1. Model Category template

   ```
   class CategoryTemplate(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   ```
2. Model Commodity

   ```
   class Commodity(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=False)
   ```

   Example Data:

   ```
   *category template
   id    | name
    1    | Pupuk
    2    | Pestisida

   *commodity
   id    | name
    1    | Pisang
    2    | Semangka
   ```

my question is, with that model how to join that model to get the result like this ?

```
 cat_temp_id | cat_temp_name | comm_id | comm_name | category
           1 |   Pupuk       |    1    | Pisang    | Pupuk Pisang
           1 |   Pupuk       |    2    | Semangka  | Pupuk Semangka
           2 |   Pestisida   |    1    | Pisang    | Pestisida Pisang
           2 |   Pestisida   |    2    | Semangka  | Pestisida Semangka
```

Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the *cartesian product*, not a *join*.

For that there is no need to mess with the models if you can just iterate over them. Simply write a nested loop

```
category_templates = CategoryTemplate.objects.all()
commodities = Commodity.objects.all()

for cat in category_templates:
    for comm in commodities:
        category = "%s %s" % (cat.name, comm.name)
```

or use `itertools.product`

```
for (cat, comm) in itertools.product(
    CategoryTemplate.objects.all(),
    Commodity.objects.all()
):
    category = "%s %s" % (cat.name, comm.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the non-relational database there is no need of join to achieve the final outcome as you do in the relational database.

What is the goal you are trying to achieve by joining two tables?